# Having issues with javascript form and Django

Tags: javascript, django, post, django-csrf

I have looked through and found posts similar to mine but everything I have seems to be in working order so I am stumped.

I have a javascript snippet that will allow the user to select one of two buildings then depending on which building is used a different set of options are given. This is using a post submit button. Everywhere has said it has to do with {% csrf_token %} but I have alread included it in the form and have the middleware in the settings.py. If it makes a difference there is also a get request on the same page.

The Form

```
<form id="formname" name="formname" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td width="41%" align="right" valign="middle">Category :</td>
            <td width="59%" align="left" valign="middle">
                <select name="category" id="category" onchange="javascript: dropdownlist(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                    <option value="">Select Building</option>
                    <option value="Marcus">Marcus</option>
                    <option value="Pettit">Pettit</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Location :</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
                    document.write('<select name="subcategory"><option value="">Select Location</option>   </select>')
                </script>
                <noscript>
                    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
                        <option value="">Select Location</option>
                    </select>
                </noscript>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <input value="Inventory Safety Log" type="submit">
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The Javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function dropdownlist(listindex) {

    document.formname.subcategory.options.length = 0;
    switch (listindex) {

        case "Marcus":
            document.formname.subcategory.options[0] = new Option("Select Location", "");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[1] = new Option("Chemical Room", "Chemicals");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[2] = new Option("Supply Room", "Supplies");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[3] = new Option("Gas Storage G205", "G205");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[4] = new Option("In-Organic Sub Fab G230", "G230");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[5] = new Option("Gas Bunker", "Gas Bunker");
            break;
        case "Pettit":
            document.formname.subcategory.options[0] = new Option("Select Location", "");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[1] = new Option("Chemical Room", "Chemicals");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[2] = new Option("Supply Room", "Supplies");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[3] = new Option("Utility Chase #19", "19");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[4] = new Option("Utility Chase #25", "25");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[5] = new Option("Utility Chase #29", "29");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[6] = new Option("Utility Chase #30", "30");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[7] = new Option("Utility Chase #36", "36");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[8] = new Option("Utility Chase #44", "44");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[9] = new Option("Gas Cage", "Gas Cage");
            document.formname.subcategory.options[10] = new Option("Bunker", "Bunker");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
```

Thanks for any input, advice, tips, or insights.

Main issue is that When I try to post the form it brings me to the csrf verification failed page.

Comment: So, what is the issue? One a side note - use a django form - your life would be so much simpler

Comment: When I try to post the form it brings me to the csrf verification failed page. Sorry I'll edit the original post to include that as well.

Comment: I would but I am really new to django and already on a very tight and almost over deadline. Was sort of thrown under the bus so to speak. But once this is over I plan on going over everything later so I can get a full grasp of django.

Comment: My guess is, since you are changing the form after the document is loaded, you are running into issues. You can use [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator in the view and see if it works for now.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to figure out. And yeah that worked. mind posting that as an answer so that I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into issues because of tampering with the form data on the fly. You need to use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) to handle it cleanly. For now, you can use the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator as a temporary workaround